# How can I get Facebook JSON reponse link?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get my statuses that starting from the day I open my app to the future days. But it is hard for me to understand the example on Facebook page. I can't image what is the reponse for GraphRequest and what code should I write to get those statuses.

```
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{status-id}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

I want a reponse link like this to know what I should do.

> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/2004614103/media/recent/?client_id=103babf92fe1445f8bc4a38a8e2cfa58&count=null

Comment: Why are you giving an API call example about Instagram and talk about Facebook ?

Comment: I mean I want to get a JSON like that, but never mind, I found a solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help someone:

```
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                "/me/posts", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                    public void onCompleted(
                                            GraphResponse response) {
                                        /* handle the result */
                                        JSONObject json = response
                                                .getJSONObject();
                                        JSONArray arr;
                                        try {
                                            arr = json.getJSONArray("data");

                                            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                                                JSONObject json_obj = arr
                                                        .getJSONObject(i);

                                                String id = json_obj
                                                        .getString("id");
                                                String message = json_obj
                                                        .getString("message");
                                                String picture = json_obj
                                                        .getString("picture");
                                                String created_time = json_obj
                                                        .getString("created_time");
                                                String test = String
                                                        .valueOf(json_obj);

                                            }
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();
```